# align image to left and text along the center of image

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a logo/image which I want to the left of the page, and word `CERTIFICATE` written along the horizontal line crossing the center of the image.

I have been using following but it writes the text `CERTIFICATE` along the horizontal line passing through the bottom of the logo, not the center.

```
\noindent\includegraphics[width = 35 mm, height = 35 mm]{image.jpg}
\hfill CERTIFICATE
```

EDIT1: Also, I want this text (CERTIFICATE) to be on the center of the page.

How to write `CERTIFICATE` along the horizontal line passing through the center of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent\_\ \rule{35mm}{35mm}\hfil
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}[b][35mm][c]{35mm}\centering
    CERTIFICATE
  \end{minipage}}
\ \_
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent\makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width = 35 mm, height = 35 mm]{example-image-a}}}%
\hfil CERTIFICATE

\noindent\dotfill X\dotfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, with `adjustbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\noindent\makebox[0pt][l]{\includegraphics[width = 35 mm, height = 35 mm,valign=c]{example-image-a}}%
\hfil CERTIFICATE

\noindent\dotfill X\dotfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want this CERTIFICATE to be on the center of the page, not on the right.

Comment: @pranavk now it is.